# Why the value not changed in recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, void

If the input: *int[] nums= [1,2,3]*, *target=4*;
why the output *res=0*; the *res* has not been accumulated?

```
    public int combinationSum4(int[] nums, int target) {
        int res=0;
        helper(nums,target,res);
        return res;
    }

    private void helper(int[] nums, int target, int res){
        if (target==0) {
            res++;
            return;
        }
        else if (target<0) return;
        else {
            for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
                helper(nums, target-nums[i],res);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java primitives are not passed by reference, but passed by values.
This means that if you pass an int to a method and increment it inside this method, the value is increased only in the scope of the method, not outside.

So `res++` only changes res inside the helper method. if you want it to do anything outside of it, you need to return it's value and assign it outside

Comment: Thanks, because I saw a piece of code written in C++, which is roughly the same as my code. So I was wondering whether C++ primitives are passed by values? (or is there something in C++, like "&", matters?)